# Perform action on selected columns depending on their name

Tags: mysql, sql, average, criteria

I've got a huge table, containing three "selection"-columns and many "data"-columns.

```
  ID   Thing1   Thing2   Thing3   avgData1   avgData2   highestEtc  
 ---- -------- -------- -------- ---------- ---------- ------------ 
   1        1        2        2        321        654          999  
   2        2        1        1        123        456           11  
   3        2        1        1        987        789           77  
   4        2        1        1        765        567           11
```

In my queries, I'm now selecting all entries with "Thing1" = x, "Thing2" = y, "Thing3" = z (Those three columns are selection-criteria.)

The purpose of getting those lines is to perform an action on each of the following data-columns: If it starts with "avg", I want to calculate an average of the specific column on all selected entries. On another prefix I want to count which number appears the most.

Is there a way of letting the MySQL Database do all this for me? I need a SQL-Statement that calculates the averages of the columns automatically, and performs other actions too.

For example, let's say I'd select the criteria Thing1=2, Thing2=1 and Thing3=1. Is there a way of writing the statement so that it returns only ONE entry, with the calculated things?

```
      Result                              
 ----------------- ----------------- ---- 
  (123+987+765)/3   (456+789+567)/3   11
```

I heard that this should be possible, and that it is a bad method of NOT letting the database perform those actions directly. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: sounds like you're storing application logic in database using a _hacky_ method?

Comment: @Ejay Until now I'm just storing "normal" data in my database. But I'd like SQL to perform some actions on the entries I query for me, so that I won't have to manipulate the result in my code (I heard it is bad to fetch something and then manipulate it)

Comment: how about manipulating it before storing and updating the _result_ field(s) in case of any calculation field updates?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
SELECT ID, AVG(avgData1) AS RESULT1, AVG(avgData2) AS RESULT2, highestEtc
FROM YOUR_TAB
WHERE Thing1 = 2
AND Thing2 = 1 
AND Thing3 = 1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(highestEtc) > 1;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work! Another question though: Is it possible to do this "dynamically"? So that I don't have to hard-code the query, but that AVG() is performed on columns with the avg prefix and min on min prefix, etc? That would be really awesome.

Comment: Oh, and actually the "MIN" is wrong; I want to get the value with the highest frequency - So in this case it is "11" and is the same result as MIN, but in other cases it could be something else. For example if I have the three values 77, 11, 77, it should return 77.

Comment: Got it working! Just had to change the "GROUP BY ID" to "GROUP BY highestEtc". Thank you so much for your help! Another question though: If  I wanted to add a column showing the count of rows BEFORE the group by, how would I do it? I added a "COUNT(ID) AS rCount", but it is only showing 2 for the example above, while it should show 3. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Oh and there is another problem: The "highestEtc"-column shows the right value, but the average is wrong, since it doesn't count the rows not fulfilling the "Having" statement